# How to send advertiserId to Segment-Analytics if iAD is deprecated

Tags: ios, facebook, idfa, facebook-analytics, segment-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Facebook App Events through Segments.

From [Segment Integration Docs](https://segment.com/docs/integrations/facebook-app-events/#troubleshooting):

> You will have to be sure that the **IDFA** is working within your app, which involves adding the **iAD framework**.
>
> Once you have added this, you will start to see the *context.device.advertiserId* populate and the *context.device.adTrackingEnabled* flag set to true.

But, [iAD was deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/iad/)!

From Apple documentation:

> **iAd Framework**
>   On your next regular app update or submission, you should remove the deprecated iAd framework and connection.

When I open the debugger in Segment, the values are not there:

```
"context": {
    "device": {
      "id": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "manufacturer": "Apple",
      "model": "x86_64",
      "type": "ios"
    },
}
```

[When submitting to the AppStore, I'm flagging YES to **IDFA** as a Segment requirement](https://segment.com/docs/sources/mobile/ios/quickstart/#step-5-submitting-to-the-app-store). So I can imagine that somehow it's connected.

Someone knows how to send *advertiserId* and *adTrackingEnabled = true* to Segment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this two lines of code:

```
import AdSupport

ASIdentifierManager.sharedManager().advertisingTrackingEnabled
```

Only using this two lines, Segment-Analytics is able to send the data to their server.

```
"device": {
  "adTrackingEnabled": true,
  "advertisingId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "id": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "manufacturer": "Apple",
  "model": "x86_64",
  "type": "ios"
},
```